# Javascript - reading in a file and iterating over sentences

Tags: javascript, html, file

I'm trying to read in a local text file to perform functions like counting syllables, characters etc.,

I am trying to do this by doing:

```
var txtFile = new XMLHttpRequest();
        txtFile.open("GET", "file://path/to/my/file.txt", true);
        txtFile.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (txtFile.readyState === 4) {  // Makes sure the document is ready to parse.
            if (txtFile.status === 200) {  // Makes sure it's found the file.
            allText = txtFile.responseText;
            //lines = txtFile.responseText.split("\r\n"); // Will separate each line into an array
        } //"\r\n" 
    }
}
```

when I try to log 'txtFile' to the command line it prints [ObjectHtmlRequest], how do i look at what i'm loading and consequently iterate over it?

I also get an error message when i try doing this piece of code

```
var text = txtFile
//$(this).val();
//document.text_input.my_text.value = newtext;
var words = new Array(text.replace(/\s/g, ' ').split(' '));
```

which worked before, but i'm guessing it's not now because i'm no longer working with text

Comment: What browser allows this? Fx allows it from the same dir but from elsewhere?

Comment: What about logging `allText`?

Comment: I use firefox, sorry i don't understand what the second part of your response says @mplungjan, you mean it won't allow files from a different directory?

Comment: Thanks @Sunyatasattva, but that doesn't produce anything at all!

Comment: I put it in the same directory and referred to that, but still get the same error

Comment: I think we are focusing on the wrong side of the problem: I think the path/to/file is just an example. **(a)** do you even `send` the request? Because in your code I can't see you sending in anywhere. **(b)** Your second chunk of code is missing a semicolon on line one, could that be the problem?

Comment: ah yes thanks, i added a semicolon but the error is the same, how would i modify 

   " var text = txtFile; "

to send the request?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most browsers won't allow JavaScript to use the local filesystem. Chrome definitely won't, I'm not sure about Firefox and the others.

What I do in that case is either :

- Use a **local web server based on the local directory** if the file you want to read is static. I usually start it with `python -mhttp.server` (Python 3) or `python -mSimpleHTTPServer` (Python 2).
- Use the latest **HTML5 File API** if you want to let the user choose the file. More information [here](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/file/dndfiles/).

*EDIT: Well, what I said isn't entirely true. Chrome allows you to use local files, but you have to start it on the command line with a special switch (`--allow-file-access-from-files`), and frankly, it's a bother and is only really intended for development. Don't rely on it for anything in production!*

Comment: Sure! In my opinion this is the wisest choice as it mimics what happens on a real web server, so the browser isn't disturbed by all that, but see my edit about Chrome ;)